# Docker for Windows10 - Kitematic

Tags: docker-for-windows

I use docker for windows and in particular Kitematic to run my images (in this case CDAP), but sometimes it stops to work correctly and it does not permit me to start an image. When I try to start it, it gaves me some errors and stops the process. I do not how to solve the problem, please help me.

Sorry for my bad english.

```
[INFO] Docker detected: running in the foreground with output to STDOUT
Wed Jul 17 15:46:05 UTC 2019 Starting CDAP Sandbox ...2019-07-17 15:46:09,639 - ERROR [main:i.c.c.StandaloneMain@427] - Failed to start Standalone CDAP
Failed to start Standalone CDAP
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: TransactionEdit was serialized with an unknown codec version 0. Was it written with a newer version of Tephra?
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1015)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1001)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAndWait(AbstractService.java:220)
at io.cdap.cdap.StandaloneMain.startUp(StandaloneMain.java:243)
at io.cdap.cdap.StandaloneMain.doMain(StandaloneMain.java:417)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at io.cdap.cdap.StandaloneMain.main(StandaloneMain.java:399)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: TransactionEdit was serialized with an unknown codec version 0. Was it written with a newer version of Tephra?
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.wrapAndThrowUnchecked(Futures.java:1015)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.getUnchecked(Futures.java:1001)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.startAndWait(AbstractService.java:220)
at org.apache.tephra.inmemory.InMemoryTransactionService.doStart(InMemoryTransactionService.java:105)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:170)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: TransactionEdit was serialized with an unknown codec version 0. Was it written with a newer version of Tephra?
at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
at org.apache.tephra.TransactionManager.replayLogs(TransactionManager.java:689)
at org.apache.tephra.TransactionManager.recoverState(TransactionManager.java:508)
at org.apache.tephra.TransactionManager.doStart(TransactionManager.java:254)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:170)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: TransactionEdit was serialized with an unknown codec version 0. Was it written with a newer version of Tephra?
at org.apache.tephra.persist.TransactionEditCodecs.decode(TransactionEditCodecs.java:66)
at org.apache.tephra.persist.TransactionEdit.readFields(TransactionEdit.java:323)
at org.apache.tephra.persist.AbstractTransactionLog$Entry.readFields(AbstractTransactionLog.java:309)
at org.apache.tephra.persist.LocalFileTransactionLog$LogReader.next(LocalFileTransactionLog.java:115)
at org.apache.tephra.TransactionManager.replayLogs(TransactionManager.java:612)
... 14 more
```

Comment: There is an issue with running Microsoft Windows and using the CDAP Local Sandbox scripts when `CDAP_HOME` is defined as a path with spaces in it. I suggest to not use a path with space characters in it for `CDAP_HOME`.

Comment: How could I solve the issue? Kitematic does not allow you to specify the path during the creation of the image

Comment: You could create a symlink?

Comment: I don't think it would help, but i did not find anything